# Nginx for guacamole but not working external LAN with proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding, rdp

i use Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 for using Guacamole as RDP clientless
This is working perfectly on my computer which is in an external LAN.

But not working in another external LAN which have blocked port.
Only port 80 and 443 can be use.

When i go to the app from my browser : http://myserverguaca/guacamole
I can see log in page and log on.
But when i try to start the RDP there is a loading then a message that say "The server take to many to time to be respond"

Do you think i have to forward another port ?
Because i have forwarded the port 8080 to 80, RDP use : 3389 but this is in localhost, don't know why i should forward this too.

I hope you can help me.

There is the configuration of my RDP access (user-mapping.xml)

```
    <user-mapping>
<connection name="rdp">
<protocol>rdp</protocol>
<param name="hostname">localhost</param>
<param name="port">3389</param>
<param name="server-layout">fr-fr-azerty</param>
<param name="ignore-cert">true</param>
</connection>
</user-mapping>
```

and my config on nginx (sites-enabled/guacamole)
`

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name vpsmyserver.net.com;

location /guacamole/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/guacamole/;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header X_Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
access_log off;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry for my english.

I don't no why but try :

like :

```
<param name="port">3389</param>
```

add :

```
<param name="username">YourUserNameWindows</param>
<param name="password">YourPassWordWindows</param>
```

and try again